# Call server site func mouse hover in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

Is there any way to implement something that will execute code in an ASP.NET code behind when the user moves their mouse outside of a button?

I can't directly use javascript and aspx code, only the ScriptManager.

Comment: Why can't you use Javascript?  Did you realize that ASP.Net is using it quite a bit in the webform already?

Comment: Sounds like you might be interested in AJAX to execute server-side code. [Here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax) is some tutorials you might be interested in.

Comment: School teacher is low in asp xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an ajax call. If you use the jquery library, you could use something like this:

```
$('#SomeObject').mouseover(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<%= Url.Action("Action", "Controller") %>",
        data: { id: x },
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("Action performed");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("An error occurred");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the onfocusout event in Javascript to fire the postback.

Comment: I cant i can only use script menager;/

Comment: Client methods are the practical way to do this. Not sure why they are putting those constraints.

Comment: The ScriptManager has an OnBubble event, check that out.